# Retrieve random row from a Table from ids in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a random row from my table with ids in my array.

The string $data has all the list of ids that i want separated by commas.

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY rand() WHERE find_in_set(id,'$data') LIMIT 1");
```

this is my query,

id is the field of my table.

Here is the error

```
An error has occurred exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE find_in_set(id,'0,1') LIMIT 1' at line 1' in
```

Comment: A Query is evaluated following sequence. "WHERE" => "GROUP BY" => "HAVING" => "ORDER BY" => "LIMIT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You need to rewrite it first. See below one

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE find_in_set(id,'$data') ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,  `ORDER BY` should be either after `where` condition or `tablename`

```
SELECT * FROM clients  WHERE find_in_set(id,'$data') ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

```
 SELECT
[ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
  [HIGH_PRIORITY]
  [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
  [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
  [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
select_expr [, select_expr ...]
[FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
[HAVING where_condition]
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ...]
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
[PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
[INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
  | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
  | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
[FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Answer (score 0):

order by clause placement is wrong in your query.

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE find_in_set(id,'$data')
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
```